# AWS lambda doesn't return binary content

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have an API which I'm deploying to AWS using CDK. I'm using the lambda proxy integration. I'm trying to create a new API call which will return a zip file, but I cannot get it to return binary data. Here's what I have:

This will eventually be called from a browser link, so I have my `binaryMediaTypes` set to `*/*` as per [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/lambda-proxy-binary-media.html) (I've also tried setting it to `application/zip`):

```
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, "cursive-api", {
    restApiName: props.apiName,
    ... etc etc ...
    binaryMediaTypes: ["*/*"]
});
```

My integration has `contentHandling` set to `CONVERT_TO_BINARY`:

```
const downloadIntegration = new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(downloadFn,
    {
        proxy: true,
        contentHandling: apigateway.ContentHandling.CONVERT_TO_BINARY
    });
```

I'm hitting this with `curl` and passing the `Accept` header:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/zip" <url>
```

I can see in CloudWatch that the accept header is making it through CloudFront ok:

```
Field           Value
@ingestionTime  1620087566765
@log            592838288812:API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_xxx/prod
@logStream      xxx
@message        (xxx) Method request headers: {Accept=application/zip, CloudFront-Viewer-Country=NZ, CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto=https, CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer=false, CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer=false, User-Agent=curl/7.64.1, X-Forwarded-Proto=https, CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer=false, Host=staging-api.cursive-ide.com, X-Forwarded-Port=443, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-xxx, Via=2.0 xxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront), X-Amz-Cf-Id=Guy-_xxx==, X-Forwarded-For=151.210.253.227, 130.176.150.98, CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer=true}
@timestamp      1620087546597
```

I can also see in CloudWatch that I'm setting isBase64Encoded and that the content-type is right:

```
Field           Value
@ingestionTime  1620087566765
@log            592838288812:API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_xxx/prod
@logStream      xxx
@message        (xxx) Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode":200,"headers":{"content-type":"application/zip","Content-Disposition":"attachment; filename=\"licences.zip\"","access-control-allow-origin":"https://<url>"},"isBase64Encoded":true,"body":"UEsDBETCETCETC [TRUNCATED]
@timestamp      1620087548798
```

However, whatever I do I only get the base64 encoded string back.

Answer (score 0):

`contentHandling` on the `LambdaIntegration` construct applies only to requests. You need to set the `contentHandling` on the integration response.

Per [documentation for `LambdaIntegrationOptions.contentHandling`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.LambdaIntegrationOptions.html#contenthandling):

> Specifies how to handle **request** payload content type conversions.

To fix it, configure `contentHandling` on `LambdaIntegrationOptions.integrationResponses` for 200 status code.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.IntegrationResponse.html